# How to monitor network traffic of running processes

Tags: networking, process, monitoring

I need a program which monitors network traffic. But like this way: It will show running processes and which IPs and websites are they getting/sending packets. I had such program, but I can't find nor remember its name. All programs I find on google searches returns me same program style which only monitors general network traffic.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wireshark on packet level. Netstat on port level (local).

to monitor a network:

- put a port on the switch as monitor port, and put the device in promiscious mode.
- use wireshark to see the traffic.

(wireshark was ethereal in the past)

Answer (score 0):

You can try LSP or WinpCap monito process traffic。
I hope this may be helpful to you.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The program you need depends on the type of architecture. If you have devices supporting Netflow, this could be very handy to identify bottlenecks or missues. There are just a few good tools for netflow under a low budget, try solarwinds or Pandora FMS.

For SNMP monitoring, probably the most common case, most tools do a good job: cacti, zabbix, pandora fms or nagios. OpenNMS and Pandora FMS have the best management of Traps, and only a few manage v3 properly.

For a mixed scope on monitoring: server, apps and networking, you have less tools, we use Pandora FMS for that reason, can manage netflow, snmp, wmi (for remote server monitoring) and agent based monitoring for unix & windows server.

Some links:

http://pandorafms.com/Producto/network-monitoring/en
http://opems.org